# Struggling with the logic in if statement

Tags: assembly, mips

So I am trying to find the greatest common denominator between 3 numbers. I think that my logic is pretty sound on how to do this and I am currently not getting the correct output.

```
li $s0, 1 

whileloop:
bgt $s0, $t0, exit 
bgt $s0, $t1, exit 
bgt $s0, $t2, exit 
    IF1:
    div $s0, $t0 
    mfhi $s1 
    bne $s1, $zero, else  


  IF2: 
    div $s0, $t1
    mfhi $s2 
    bne $s2, $zero, else  

   IF3:
   div $s0, $t2 
   mfhi $s3 
   bne $s3, $zero, else 
   sw $s0, 4($s4)
   j else 

    else: 
    addi $s0, $s0, 1 
    j whileloop 


exit: 

    la $a0, answer 
    syscall 

    move $a0, $s4 
    li $v0, 1 
    syscall 

    li $v0, 10 
    syscall
```

The three numbers are user inputted into $t0, $t1, and $t2.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is sound but your div instructions are incorrect.  Reverse the arguments on all three.  For example, you're doing `s1 = s0 % t0` and you want `s1 = t0 % s0`

WARNING: You can't do multiply/divide within two instructions after mflo/mfhi, so you need to add a nop here and there.  See http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-14/ass14_5.html  In particular, your div's at if2/if3 violate this in the fall through case.

Personally, I'd fix this by changing it *after* the mfhi rather than *before* the div.  IMO, that's cleaner because the restriction comes from mfhi [not div], so associate the compensation with it.  And, for the sake of regularity, I'd put it on all three mfhi's even though one doesn't actually need it.

Change:

```
    mfhi ...
    bne ...

ifX:
    div ...
```

Into:

```
    mfhi ...
    nop
    bne ...

ifX:
    div ...
```

Just for fun, here's your program translated back into C:

```
int
gcd(int t0,int t1,int t2)
{
    int s0;
    int s1;
    int s2;
    int s3;
    int rtn;

    rtn = -1;

    s0 = 1;

Lloop:
    if (s0 > t0) goto Lexit;
    if (s0 > t1) goto Lexit;
    if (s0 > t2) goto Lexit;

Lif1:
#if 0
    s1 = s0 % t0;
#else
    s1 = t0 % s0;
#endif
    if (s1 != 0) goto Lelse;

Lif2:
#if 0
    s2 = s0 % t1;
#else
    s2 = t1 % s0;
#endif
    if (s2 != 0) goto Lelse;

Lif3:
#if 0
    s3 = s0 % t2;
#else
    s3 = t2 % s0;
#endif
    rtn = s0;
    if (s3 != 0) goto Lelse;

Lelse:
    s0 += 1;
    goto Lloop;

Lexit:
    return rtn;
}
```